# What exceptions should be captured when reading web file

Tags: android, exception

**Update 1**

main.java file

```
//how would i return those errors on the main.java file? so that i can display on the UI.
directory_listings = obj.get_webpage_source();
```

**end**

I am new to Android mobile application development. I would like to know, how can I handle the exception like HttpConnection related exceptions or any other important exceptions.

i am thinking of top of my head:

server is down
file not exists
no data found

my code is here:

the below code is in its own java class and i am calling this code from main.java

```
public class Get_Webpage {

public String get_webpage_source(){

 HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
 HttpGet request = new HttpGet(parsing_url);
 HttpResponse response = null;
 ...............
 ...............
 ...............
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to catch all the below exception when reading file from the web.

```
 try
  {
  }
  catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "error";
        }
        catch (ConnectTimeoutException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "error"; 
        }
        catch (ClientProtocolException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "error";
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
           e.printStackTrace();
           return "error";
        } 
        finally {
            client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        }
```

Comment: thanks Chirag, so how would i show those custom error on the UI since i have two .java files, `get_access.java` is what will be connecting to internet and downloading the files and if anything goes wrong here i want to display that error back to UI.. any thoughts on this?

Comment: when there is any exception occur at that time you need to return the string like error occurs or any other string. In main java file you can compare that string and show the error.

Comment: i have update my answer . In java file you need to compare directory_listings.equalIgnoreCase("error") .